# Tree representation using list in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tree

For this tree,

### [image]

As a beginner, Below is my list representation,

```
tree = [
          [
              [
                 [
                   [], 3, []
                 ], 
                 10,
                 [
                   [], 17, []
                 ]
              ],
              25,
              [
                 [
                   [], 30, []
                 ],
                 32,
                 [
                   [], 38, []
                 ]
              ]
          ],
          40,
          [
             [
               [], 50, []
             ], 
             78,
             [
               [], 93, []
             ]
          ]
       ]
```

Is this representation correct using python list?

Can I avoid empty list `[]` in this representation?

Comment: It is a possible representation. It is not the only possible representation. It is, however, one of the more natural ones. There is nothing wrong with it, nor is there anything wrong with having empty lists. If your tree is not meant to be modified, using always the same empty list would reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: @Amadan What are the other possible representations? Am still not clear, whether to place empty list, because base case recursion code will be like `return type(tree) != list` for elements in tree = `[]`, which is empty

Comment: For an obvious and trivial change, you could have `[value, left, right]` instead of `[left, value, right]` - this format would make it trivial to support non-binary trees. You could use `None` instead of the empty list, even though it would complicate the traversal a bit. You could use custom `Node` objects or tuples instead. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Also, your leaves are nodes with values but no descendants; another representation might have leaves as plain values, and not nodes at all. So instead of `[[], 3, []]`, you'd just have `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You representation makes a lot of sense since it uses just 2 simple rules. A tree is a list that can be:

```
[]                          #empty tree
[list, number, list]        #non-empty tree
```

This simplicity makes it easy to write code for and treat things in an uniform way (and without a lot of if statements).

Another equally simple representation is to use tuples instead of lists and/or use None for empty tree.

Another representation would be to put the numbers in leaf nodes directly in the parent node (e.g. to code the subtree under 10 as [3, 10, 17]). This is more compact and gets rid of empty lists but now the logic is more complex, and a tree could be represented 5 different ways:

```
[]
[list, number, list]
[list, number, number]
[number, number, list]
[number, number, number]
```

The representation being more complex means you probably need to write more code.

Comment: i think i should remove empty braces, because it is breaking the definition of leaf node.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by 'represent'. You can represent trees by just having the elements in a list e.g. list = [40,25,78,10,32,50,93,3,17,30,38] Then to iterate through it if you want to recreate the tree you can iterate through the list since you know that the life child of list[(i+1)*2-1] and the right child is list[(i+1)*2].

Note: you have to do i+1 since the first element has index 0, And I is the index of the parent node, e.g. the index+1 of the of 25 is 2 therefore the index+1 of 25's left child is 4.

Comment: what if it is n-ary tree? Can we follow your representation?

Comment: If `n` is fixed, yes, just replace all `2` with `n`.

Comment: I think you want (i+1)*2 - 1 and (i + 1) * 2. For 0 your method gives 2 and 3, when you want 1 and 2.

Comment: I think this is something like doing tree recursion on flattened list.

Comment: Yeah (i+1)*2-1 is right,  I had the index shifted forward on one my head and forgot to correct it.

Comment: @TimothyMurphy What is the advantage of using such representation, when computation is more complex?

Comment: A flat list representation is useful for complete (or mostly complete) binary tries. IE all levels above the bottom level are full. The bottom level is filled from left to the last element in the tree. As is the case for you example tree. It's useful because it's easy enough to calculate your children (and your parent) and it's a less complicated structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to represent a tree using lists.

You can use a single dimensional list. This works well for full trees with a set number of children. Or for missing children pad the array with None where the child of a leaf node should be.
if the current node is at index i, its children will be at index i*2 + 1 and (i+1)*2.  your parent will be (i-1)/2.

You could also use the a lisp-like tree representation.

[Root, LEFT_SUB_TREE, RIGHT_SUB_TREE]

you example tree would look like:

```
[40, [25, [10, 3, 17], [32, 30, 38]], [78, 50, 93]]
```

leaf nodes don't need to be a list they can just be their value.

This method uses less memory for spare trees than the single dimensional list representation.

It is also easy to make this work for any nary tree as well, with varying number of children per node.

[Root, SUB_TREE_1, SUB_TREE_2, ..., SUB_TREE_n]

Comment: As I said above, my base case is `return type(tree) != list`

Comment: The second representation should work quite well for you then. The children of 10: 3 and 7 are not of type list, same with the children of 32 and 78 (i. e) all leaf nodes are not of type list.